# populate different data in listview according to spinner selection in android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have one spinner and I want to to populate the custom listview with the the data according to spinner selection. Data is coming from mysql database. Currently I am able to get the data from different spinner selection but the problem is when I try to add the data in listview it doesn't remove previous data from listview.

I tried `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but this didn,t worked for me. Even I created 2 adapters for different spinner selections and tried to add them to list according to spinner selection but this gives me blank list.

I saw multiple solutions for my problem but nothing worked for me.
So please give me some suitable idea for adding different data to listview according to spinner selection.

Thanks in advance

this is my adapter class

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
//static String get_empcode,get_empname,get_app_date,get_nod,get_from,get_to,get_lv_type,get_reason,get_remark,get_status;
static List list=new ArrayList();
static String[]  get_empcode,get_empname,get_app_date,get_nod,get_from,get_to,get_lv_type,get_reason,get_remark,get_status;
static ArrayList<String> empcode = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> from = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> to = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> lv_type = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> nod = new ArrayList<String>();

static int count=0;



int i;
static int arr_length;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);

}

public void add(Details object) {

    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
}

@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
}

public int getCount() {

    return list.size();
}


@Override
public Details getItem(int position) {

    return (Details) list.get(position);
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     View row;
    row=convertView;
    final DetailsHolder detailsHolder;

    if(row==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout_approval, parent, false);
        detailsHolder=new DetailsHolder();
        detailsHolder.empcode=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.empcode1);
        detailsHolder.empname=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.empname1);
        detailsHolder.appdate=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.appdate1);
        detailsHolder.lv_type=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.lv_type1);
        detailsHolder.from=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.from1);
        detailsHolder.to=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.to1);
        detailsHolder.nod=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nod1);
        detailsHolder.reason=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.reason1);
        detailsHolder.status=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.status1);
        DetailsHolder.cb2=(CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.cb2);





       DetailsHolder.cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked)
                    {

                        count=count+1;
                        empcode.add((String) detailsHolder.empcode.getText());
                        from.add((String) detailsHolder.from.getText());
                        to.add((String) detailsHolder.to.getText());
                        lv_type.add((String) detailsHolder.lv_type.getText());
                        nod.add((String) detailsHolder.nod.getText());




                    }

                else{
                    count=count-1;
                    empcode.remove(position);
                    from.remove(position);
                    to.remove(position);
                    lv_type.remove(position);
                    nod.remove(position);



                }

                arr_length=empcode.size()+from.size()+to.size()+lv_type.size()+nod.size();

            }


        });







        row.setTag(detailsHolder);





    }
    else{

        detailsHolder=(DetailsHolder) row.getTag();

    }







    Details details=(Details)this.getItem(position);
    detailsHolder.empcode.setText(details.getEmpcode());
    detailsHolder.empname.setText(details.getEmpname());
    detailsHolder.appdate.setText(details.getApplyDate());
    detailsHolder.lv_type.setText(details.getLeave_type());
    detailsHolder.from.setText(details.getFrom());
    detailsHolder.to.setText(details.getTo());
    detailsHolder.nod.setText(details.getNod());
    detailsHolder.reason.setText(details.getReason());
    detailsHolder.status.setText(details.getStatus());

    return row;
}





static class DetailsHolder
{
    TextView empcode,empname,appdate,lv_type,from,to,nod,reason,status;
    EditText remark;
    static CheckBox cb2;




}
```

}

below is details class:-

public class Details {

```
private String empcode,empname,applyDate,leave_type,from,to,nod,reason,remark,status;


public Details(String empcode,String empname,String applyDate,String leave_type,String from,
        String to,String nod,String reason,String status){

    this.setEmpcode(empcode);
    this.setEmpname(empname);
    this.setApplyDate(applyDate);
    this.setLeave_type(leave_type);
    this.setFrom(from);
    this.setTo(to);
    this.setNod(nod);
    this.setReason(reason);
    this.setStatus(status);



}


public String getEmpcode() {
    return empcode;
}

public void setEmpcode(String empcode) {
    this.empcode = empcode;
}

public String getEmpname() {
    return empname;
}

public void setEmpname(String empname) {
    this.empname = empname;
}

public String getApplyDate() {
    return applyDate;
}

public void setApplyDate(String applyDate) {
    this.applyDate = applyDate;
}

public String getLeave_type() {
    return leave_type;
}

public void setLeave_type(String leave_type) {
    this.leave_type = leave_type;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}

public String getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void setTo(String to) {
    this.to = to;
}

public String getNod() {
    return nod;
}

public void setNod(String nod) {
    this.nod = nod;
}

public String getReason() {
    return reason;
}

public void setReason(String reason) {
    this.reason = reason;
}


public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

}

And in mainActivity I am passing data as follows:

public class Leave_approval extends Activity {

```
String JSON_STRING,php_result,LeaveType,empcode,FullName,ApplyDate,From,To,NOD,Reason,Status,bundle_id,approve_bkg_result;
String from_date,to_date,appdate;

String LeaveType1,empcode1,FullName1,ApplyDate1,From1,To1,NOD1,Reason1,Status1,bundle_id1,from_date1,to_date1,appdate1;
String[] status_data;
String[] empcode_val,lv_type_val,nod_value,status_val,from_value,to_value;
JSONObject jsonObject;
JSONArray jsonArray;
String[] date_list;
Details details;
TextView head;
ListAdapter listAdapter;
Approve_List_adapter approve_adapter;
ListView listView;
CheckBox cb1;
static Boolean cb_status;
int i;
Spinner status;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.leave_approval);
    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    cb1=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
    status=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status);


    listAdapter=new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout_approval);
  // approve_adapter=new Approve_List_adapter(this, R.layout.approve_list_adapter);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    //listView.setAdapter(approve_adapter);

    head=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.head);
     Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

     php_result=b.getString("json_data");
     bundle_id = b.getString("string");

    status_data=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.status);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,status_data);
    status.setAdapter(adapter);

    status.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            String status_changed=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
            if(status_changed.equals("Approved"))
            {


                LeaveApprovedStatus bkg=new  LeaveApprovedStatus(getApplicationContext());
                bkg.execute(bundle_id);


            }

            else{

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status_changed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                 try {
                        jsonObject=new JSONObject(php_result);
                        jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            LeaveType=c.getString("LeaveType");
                            empcode=c.getString("empcode");
                            FullName=c.getString("FullName");
                            ApplyDate=c.getString("ApplyDate");
                            From=c.getString("From");
                            To=c.getString("To");
                            NOD=c.getString("NOD");
                            Reason=c.getString("Reason");
                            Status=c.getString("Status");

                            String[] from_array=From.split("-");
                            String[] to_array=To.split("-");
                            String[] apply_array=ApplyDate.split("-");
                            String from_date,to_date,appdate;


                            if(from_array[1].equals("01"))
                                from_array[1]="jan";

                            if(from_array[1].equals("02"))
                                from_array[1]="Feb";

                            if(from_array[1].equals("03"))
                                from_array[1]="Mar";

                            if(from_array[1].equals("04"))
                                from_array[1]="Apr";

                            if(from_array[1].equals("05"))
                                from_array[1]="May";

                            if(from_array[1].equals("06"))
                                from_array[1]="Jun";

                            if(from_array[1].equals("07"))
                                from_array[1]="Jul";

                            if(from_array[1].equals("08"))
                                from_array[1]="Aug";

                            if(from_array[1].equals("09"))
                                from_array[1]="Sep";

                            if(from_array[1].equals("10"))
                                from_array[1]="Oct";

                            if(from_array[1].equals("11"))
                                from_array[1]="Nov";


                            if(from_array[1].equals("12"))
                                from_array[1]="Dec";



                            if(to_array[1].equals("01"))
                                to_array[1]="jan";

                            if(to_array[1].equals("02"))
                                from_array[1]="Feb";

                            if(to_array[1].equals("03"))
                                to_array[1]="Mar";

                            if(to_array[1].equals("04"))
                                to_array[1]="Apr";

                            if(to_array[1].equals("05"))
                                to_array[1]="May";

                            if(to_array[1].equals("06"))
                                to_array[1]="Jun";

                            if(to_array[1].equals("07"))
                                to_array[1]="Jul";

                            if(to_array[1].equals("08"))
                                to_array[1]="Aug";

                            if(to_array[1].equals("09"))
                                to_array[1]="Sep";

                            if(to_array[1].equals("10"))
                                to_array[1]="Oct";

                            if(to_array[1].equals("11"))
                                to_array[1]="Nov";


                            if(to_array[1].equals("12"))
                                to_array[1]="Dec";




                            if(apply_array[1].equals("01"))
                                apply_array[1]="jan";

                            if(apply_array[1].equals("02"))
                                apply_array[1]="Feb";

                            if(apply_array[1].equals("03"))
                                apply_array[1]="Mar";

                            if(apply_array[1].equals("04"))
                                apply_array[1]="Apr";

                            if(apply_array[1].equals("05"))
                                apply_array[1]="May";

                            if(apply_array[1].equals("06"))
                                apply_array[1]="Jun";

                            if(apply_array[1].equals("07"))
                                apply_array[1]="Jul";

                            if(apply_array[1].equals("08"))
                                apply_array[1]="Aug";

                            if(apply_array[1].equals("09"))
                                apply_array[1]="Sep";

                            if(apply_array[1].equals("10"))
                                apply_array[1]="Oct";

                            if(apply_array[1].equals("11"))
                                apply_array[1]="Nov";


                            if(apply_array[1].equals("12"))
                                apply_array[1]="Dec";

                            from_date=from_array[2]+"-"+from_array[1]+"-"+from_array[0];
                            to_date=to_array[2]+"-"+to_array[1]+"-"+to_array[0];
                            appdate=apply_array[2]+"-"+apply_array[1]+"-"+apply_array[0];



                            details=new Details(empcode,FullName,appdate,LeaveType,from_date,to_date,NOD,Reason,Status);

                            listAdapter.add(details);

                            //listView.invalidate();



                          }




                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }






            }


        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}


    });
```

}

```
public void approve(View view){

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(ListAdapter.count), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ArrayList<String> emplist=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> fromlist=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tolist=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> lv_typelist=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> nodlist=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> status=new ArrayList<>();


    emplist=ListAdapter.getemplist();
    fromlist=ListAdapter.getfromlist();
    tolist=ListAdapter.gettolist();
    lv_typelist=ListAdapter.getlv_typelist();
    nodlist=ListAdapter.getnodlist();
    status.add("Approved");


    JSONArray jArr1= new JSONArray();
    for(String data:emplist)
     {
       jArr1.put(data);
     }


    JSONArray jArr2= new JSONArray();
    for(String data:fromlist)
     {
       jArr2.put(data);
     }

    JSONArray jArr3= new JSONArray();
    for(String data:tolist)
     {
       jArr3.put(data);
     }

    JSONArray jArr4= new JSONArray();
    for(String data:lv_typelist)
     {
       jArr4.put(data);
     }

    JSONArray jArr5= new JSONArray();
    for(String data:status)
     {
       jArr5.put(data);
     }

    JSONArray jArraySet = new JSONArray();
      jArraySet.put(jArr1);
      jArraySet.put(jArr2);
      jArraySet.put(jArr3);
      jArraySet.put(jArr4);
      jArraySet.put(jArr5);

      String json_string=String.valueOf(jArraySet);
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json_string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(getApplicationContext());
    backgroundTask.execute(json_string);



}


@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        listView.onWindowFocusChanged(true);
        listView.invalidate();
        listView.invalidateViews();
    }
}


public void reject(View view){


    ArrayList<String> emplist=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> fromlist=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tolist=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> lv_typelist=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> nodlist=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> status=new ArrayList<>();


    emplist=ListAdapter.getemplist();
    fromlist=ListAdapter.getfromlist();
    tolist=ListAdapter.gettolist();
    lv_typelist=ListAdapter.getlv_typelist();
    nodlist=ListAdapter.getnodlist();
    status.add("Rejected");


    JSONArray jArr1= new JSONArray();
    for(String data:emplist)
     {
       jArr1.put(data);
     }


    JSONArray jArr2= new JSONArray();
    for(String data:fromlist)
     {
       jArr2.put(data);
     }

    JSONArray jArr3= new JSONArray();
    for(String data:tolist)
     {
       jArr3.put(data);
     }

    JSONArray jArr4= new JSONArray();
    for(String data:lv_typelist)
     {
       jArr4.put(data);
     }

    JSONArray jArr5= new JSONArray();
    for(String data:status)
     {
       jArr5.put(data);
     }

    JSONArray jArraySet = new JSONArray();
      jArraySet.put(jArr1);
      jArraySet.put(jArr2);
      jArraySet.put(jArr3);
      jArraySet.put(jArr4);
      jArraySet.put(jArr5);

      String json_string=String.valueOf(jArraySet);
     //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json_string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(getApplicationContext());
    backgroundTask.execute(json_string);




    }




public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

     AsyncResponse delegate = null;

     Context ctx;  
       BackgroundTask(Context ctx)  
       {  
        this.ctx =ctx;  
       }


       @Override  
       protected void onPreExecute() {  

       }  

       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {  



               String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/neha/leave_approval_json.php";
               String json_data = params[0];

                   try {  
                     URL url = new URL(login_url);  
                     HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();  
                     httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");  
                     httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);  
                     httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);  
                     OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();  
                     BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));  
                     String data = URLEncoder.encode("json_data","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(json_data,"UTF-8");          

                     bufferedWriter.write(data);  
                     bufferedWriter.flush();  
                     bufferedWriter.close();  
                     outputStream.close();  
                     InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();  
                     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));  
                     String response = "";  
                     String line = "";  
                     while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)  
                     {  
                       response+= line;  
                     }  
                     bufferedReader.close();  
                     inputStream.close();  
                     httpURLConnection.disconnect();  
                     return response;  
                   } catch (MalformedURLException e) {  
                     e.printStackTrace();  
                   } catch (IOException e) {  
                     e.printStackTrace();  
                   }  
                // }  
                 return null;  
               }  
               @Override  
               protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {  
                 super.onProgressUpdate(values);  
               }  
               @Override  
               protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 


                     Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                }  







}




class LeaveApprovedStatus extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    String json_url;


    Context ctx;  

    LeaveApprovedStatus(Context ctx)  
       {  
        this.ctx =ctx;  
       }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {


    }




    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        json_url = "http://10.0.2.2/neha/leave_approval_approvedStatus.php";


        final String empcode = params[0];  

           try {  
             URL url = new URL(json_url);  
             HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();  
             httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");  
             httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);  
             httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);  
             OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();  
             BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));  
           String data = URLEncoder.encode("empcode","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(empcode,"UTF-8");  
             bufferedWriter.write(data);  
             bufferedWriter.flush();  
             bufferedWriter.close();  
             outputStream.close(); 

             InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();  
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1")); 

             StringBuilder stringBuilder1=new StringBuilder();
             while((JSON_STRING=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
             {

                 stringBuilder1.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");




             }

             bufferedReader.close();
             inputStream.close();
             httpURLConnection.disconnect();
             return stringBuilder1.toString().trim();




        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;








    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        approve_bkg_result=result;





                Details details1=new Details (empcode1,FullName1,appdate1,LeaveType1,from_date1,to_date1,NOD1,Reason1,Status1);
                listAdapter.add(details1);
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.invalidate();






              }




           } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }










    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

So supposing you store your data in an ArrayList:

```
private ArrayList<VideoPreview> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can populate it in the spinner onItemSelectedListener:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position != currentPosition) {
                    dataList.clear();
                    dataList = myData[position];
                    dataListView.getAdapter().notifyOnDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Without knowing anything else of your problem and code, I cannot give you a more specific solution.

Your declaration of the adapter should look similar to this:

```
    final DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(getContext(), dataList);
    dataListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I am sending data through object to adapter class. can u tell me how I can use this on object??

Comment: Implement your adapter and use it as I post.

Comment: This is how I am passing data to adapterDetails details1=new Details (empcode1,FullName1,appdate1,LeaveType1,from_date1,to_date1,NOD1,Reason1,Status1);
     listAdapter.add(details1);
     listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 listView.invalidate();

Answer (score 0):

If the data object you are passing is `ArrayList<MyObject>`

just make your custom adapter extend  `ArrayAdapter<MyObject>` instead of `BaseAdapter`. Implement the required methods (leave default) and you should be fine.

Comment: I am using same still no use

Comment: Or just set adapter on list view again after data changes. Not optional but will work.

Comment: i tried this too. It shows me blank list every time I click on spinner

Comment: i'd advise you to share the code in the question. It must be something else going wrong.

Comment: use `public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>`

Comment: just tell me how can I remove previous data from list so that new data can be shown on full list